# Unable to install application through terminal

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center

I am new to Ubuntu and do not know much about command line either.
Recently I was trying to install `gcc` compiler through terminal command and it always displays this error to me:

```
E: Malformed line 54 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Malformed line 54 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I do not know what this error is. So please help me fix this, educate me about why it is displayed.

After using this command:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

it opened a file, but I do not know what to do now

the line with c is line number 54

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted c

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted

Answer (score 3):

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted c
```

is invalid. It needs to be

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
```